# C++ Arduino How can I initialize anything an uninitialized global variable in a method?

Tags: java, c++, arduino

I have a problem with C++

Also:

- I have a variable, a global variable
- I have the library LiquidCrystal for Arduino Uno

I'll:

- The global variable should be initialize in a method.

My Code:

> Declaration

```
LiquidCrystal lcd;
```

> Initialazion

```
void Crystal::begin(){
    lcd = LiquidCrystal(1,2,3,4,5,6);
}
```

> Error:
>   Initialazion!

My Question:

> How can I initialize anything an uninitialized global variable in a method?

Comment: Is that the full text of the error message you're getting from the compiler?

Comment: Which language, Java or C++?  Big difference when declaring, assigning and copying variables.

Comment: Error: Initialazion! Correct: Initialization. ... please post the full error message

Comment: I didn't see any copy constructors or assignment operators for the LCD class.  Does it allow assigning?  Or do you have to declare 1 instance and pass references around?

Answer (score 1):

Since the constructor arguments are meant to set the IO pin configuration for the LCD and those are compile time constants, I don't see a reason why the global object can't be initialised immediately:

```
LiquidCrystal lcd(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

If it MUST be done in the function `void Crystal::begin()` then the only option is to create the object dynamically.

```
LiquidCrystal *lcd;

void Crystal::begin()
{
    lcd = new LiquidCrystal(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
}
```

Just make sure to delete the object when you're done with it. Of course, if the object has to live forever, which is possible since it is global and this is a embedded project so the program never really ends, then you don't ever have to delete it.